# How to interpret a matrix operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question

Suppose we have a 3-term vector $v_1 = [1, 2, 3]$, and another 3-term vector $v_2 = [16, 20, 22]$. Now suppose we find a 3 x 3 matrix $$M = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 3 & 7 \\ 9 & -2 & 6 \\ 0 & 7 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ so that $v_1 \cdot M = v_2$. How could we interpret such an operation in physical terms? Or, more generally, what have we done to the first vector to get the second?

Comment: I'd like to help, but please use LaTex, in order for the question to be clearer. Also, I didn't understand what you mean by M=v2. Please edit your question. Thank you

Comment: Noting that $(v_1M)^T=M^Tv_1^T$ the matrix multiplication in question is just a way of rewriting usual matrix multiplication. So they're linear transformations - rotations, shears, dilations etc.

Comment: $v_2$ is the sum of the weighted rows of $M.$ the first row is weighted by $1,$ second by $2$ and the third by $3$ these are the components of $v_1,$ you call them terms.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a representation of $3$ equations with $3$ linear variables. For your example, you may consider this case:

On a certain day, a shop pays $2$ $\$1$ coins, earns $9$ $\$2$ coins and earns $0$ $\$3$ coins. As a result, the shop totally earns $\$16$.

On the next day, the shop earns $3$ $\$1$ coins, pays $2$ $\$2$ coins and earns $7$ $\$3$ coins. As a result, the shop totally earns $\$20$.

On the third day, the shop earns $7$ $\$1$ coins, earns $6$ $\$2$ coins and earns $1$ $\$3$ coin. As a result, the shop totally earns $\$22$.

In this example, if you evaluate $v_1 \times M$ to get $v_2$, you are finding out the earnings of the shop in each of the three days.

But more likely, $M$ and $v_2$ are given, while you need to find $v_1$. In this example, it can be translated to "find out the denomination of the three types of coins".

So the common way of expressing this is assuming $v_1 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{array} \right) $, and the system of equations is written as:

$v_1 = \left( \begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{matrix} \right) \times 
\left( \begin{matrix}
-2 & 3 & 7 \\ 
9 & -2 & 6 \\ 
0 & 7 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix}
16 & 20 & 22 \end{matrix} \right) $

And, as pointed out by one of the comments under the OP's question, it is more likely to write the system of equations as $M^T \times v_1^T = v_2^T$:

$\left( \begin{matrix}
-2 & 9 & 0 \\ 
3 & -2 & 7 \\ 
7 & 6 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \times \left( \begin{matrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix}
16 \\ 20 \\ 22 \end{matrix} \right) $